# Settings for the Batch import tool

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing

How often does the Neo4j 2.2 batch import tool flush the data in the cache to disk? I believe this the `n` for `PERIODIC COMMIT n` and can I change this?

Also, is there any way that I can edit the default memory mappings for the import tool? I used to be able to do this with Michael Hunger's [batch import tool](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new import tool writes continuously and concurrently to disk, so a really fast disk is making a big difference.

It also manages memory completely on its own there is no configuration needed.

If you can provide the data fast enough it can saturate an SSD-RAID writing 1GB/s.